# Any way to search structurally in Intellij for scala or python sources?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

On IJ version `2016.2`  the following dialog box appears:

[image]

It includes `java` and `html` derivatives plus a small assortment of other languages. But `python` and `scala` are conspicuously missing. Is there any workaround to get such functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python and Scala are currently not supported in Structural Search and Replace. You may want to vote for the following tickets:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15003
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4599